# computing a limit

Tags: analysis

let $ a $ real number and let $u_{n}=n^a$, let p a  positive integer larger then $a$, help me to prove that the limit of $ (\Delta^p)_n= \sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^{p-i}\binom {p} {i}u_{n+i}$ is $0$  when n goes to infinity,  $\Delta$ is the euler transform defined by : $ \Delta(u)_{n}= u_{n+1}-u_{n}$ and $\Delta^p=\Delta o\Delta^{p-1}$
Thank you very much

Comment: but n^a isn't a polynomial

Comment: I accidentally read it as 'a' being a positive integer, and deleted my comment after realizing my error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Using, for example, the fact that differences can be written down as integrals,
$$
\Delta  f(x)=f(x+\Delta   x)-f(x)=\int_0^{\Delta  x}f'(x+y_1)\, dy_1,
$$
$$
\Delta^2 f(x)=f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)=\int_0^{\Delta  x}\int_0^{\Delta  x}f''(x+y_1+y_2)\,dy_1dy_2,
$$
etc and the mean value theorem.